# Boolean logic with Rails ENV variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Since Rails ENV variables should only have string values it could be the problem to decide how to use ENV variable for use cases which need boolean logic. For example since ENV variable have a string value and it would always be truthy it wouldn't be too nice to do something like that:

```
if ENV['MY_VARIABLE']
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

So there are at least 2 ways to accomplish things like above:

Initialize variable with particular value and check it

```
if ENV['MY_VARIABLE'] == 'some string'
  # do something
elsif ENV['MY_VARIABLE'] == 'some other string'
  # do something else
end
```

Or just initialize variable with any value and check if it was initialized (the code could be exactly as we wanted).

```
if ENV['MY_VARIABLE']
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

The question is what option is more preferred and what pros and cons each of them could have?

Comment: It should be `ENV['MY_VARIABLE'] == 'some string'` because using something like `ENV[MY_VARIABLE]` will always return true regardless of the value

Comment: @Mr.Alien, that's what I mean. You just initialize your variable with any value or don't initialize it at all. And then you check if it has any value (e.g. was initialized)

Comment: Depends on (1) the way you are using it (2) is there a sensible default.

Comment: `eval("true") == true`

Comment: If you use `eval("true") with a dynamic input, what if I set `MY_VARIABLE="exit()"`? Probably worth avoiding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably refactor your code and use a custom class, so it's more maintenable and changes may be done easily:

```
class MyEnv
  TRUTHY_VALUES = %w(t true yes y 1).freeze
  FALSEY_VALUES = %w(f false n no 0).freeze

  attr_reader :value

  def initialize(name)
    @value = ENV[name].to_s.downcase
  end

  def to_boolean
    return true if TRUTHY_VALUES.include?(value.to_s)
    return false if FALSEY_VALUES.include?(value.to_s)
    # You can even raise an exception if there's an invalid value
    raise "Invalid value '#{value}' for boolean casting"
  end
end

# Usage example:
MyEnv.new("MY_VARIABLE").to_boolean
```

I think that, for boolean environment variables, it's more human-friendly to have values like `yes`, `true`, `no`... instead of present or not present variables.

The only drawback that I can see here is performance, where you jump from nil checking (easy) to a comparisson of strings (a little bit more complex). Give the computer power these days, and if performance is not an issue for you, it would be no problem for you.

So, in conclussion: strings-checks are more human friendly and slower, presence-checks are faster but more obscure.

Comment: Sounds good; you could even define `self.fetch_boolean` so you can do `MyEnv.fetch_boolean("MY_VARIABLE")` so it's a more similar API to the existing `ENV.fetch(x)`.

Comment: Small thing - use `include?` instead of `includes?` here. Also consider adding 0 and 1 as strings in your falsey/truthy values respectively. In my case, I'm also considering an empty string falsey in a separate check.

Comment: Either this answer was taken verbatim (last half) from (Boolean logic with Rails ENV variables)[https://newbedev.com/boolean-logic-with-rails-env-variables]. Or said article stole this answer. ‍♀️

Comment: @MetroSmurf That website you linked literally copy-pasted all answers from this thread.

Comment: @Wikiti - Soooo.... stackoverflow? 

Comment: Falsey values are already defined by Rails, so there is no need to re-define the same thing again: `
FALSE_VALUES = [ false, 0, "0", :"0", "f", :f, "F", :F, "false", :false, "FALSE", :FALSE, "off", :off, "OFF", :OFF, ].to_set.freeze`.

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Type/Boolean.html

Answer (score 14):

If you use Rails 5+, you can do `ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(ENV['MY_VARIABLE'])`.

In Rails 4.2, use `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user(ENV['MY_VARIABLE'])`.

Documentation Rails 5+: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Type/Boolean.html

Answer (score 5):

**Environment Variables** as the name suggests, are environment dependent variables which store different values for same keys based on the environment(production, staging, development) you working on.

e.g. it holds an **Access_Key** for some api which has sandbox mode and production mode. Thus, to make your code DRY and effective you set an environment variable to get that access_key of sandbox mode for development/staging and live key for production.

What you are trying to do is use them unlike the reason they are defined for, no doubt they can be used that way. Since they are constants what I recommend is doing the following.

create a `constants.rb` file in your initializers containing

```
class Constant
  BOOL_CONSTANT = ENV['MY_VARIABLE'].present?
  # OR
  BOOL_CONSTANT = ENV['MY_VARIABLE'] == 'true'
end
```

then you can use it anywhere you like. This way you can achieve what you want to but under the hood. ;)

Comment: Are you saying that there is no environment variable with just two values?

Comment: what do you mean by `with just two values`?

Comment: Why is an environment variable that just says if you are running a unix environment or considered *"trying to use them unlike the reason they are defined for"*.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to have boolean meaning environment variables is what I'm saying.

Comment: ofcourse it is valid, instead I too have used them as `boolean` in many cases in my project, but according to me it is not recommended and even if you have to do it, I prefer the approach in the answer which is much better that fetching env var every time. Changing env var anyways needs server restart and so the initialiser, so they go together well.

Comment: The way I read the question it is asking exactly what you didn't give a definitive answer of. In other words, OP wants to know if he should use `ENV['MY_VARIABLE'].present?` or `ENV['MY_VARIABLE'] == 'true'`.

Comment: so, in my answer, both doesn't make a difference to me as they are just returning boolean value. it is similar to say which is better `0 == 0` OR `0.zero?`. What I wanted to highlight is the implementation and recommended/better approach to the same.

Comment: They are not the same. `x == 0` and `x.zero?` are different. If `x` is `nil`, the latter will throw an error, while the former will give you `false`. The same way, just checking for if if an environment variable is set will always give you a default (it's not set), while if you have to set it to one of two values, you can check if it is one of the two values and if it not - you can output an error. Also if you build your environment automatically it is easier to set each variable to one of two values then it is to sometimes set them and sometimes - not.

Comment: There are a lot of subtle differences. OP is asking what are the pros and cons of each. He is not asking how to use environment variables in his code once he picks one or the other, but how he should represent boolean values with environment variables.

Comment: maybe I choose the wrong example, still I want to mention when x is nil, `x == 0` will result in `false` and not `true`. Also, I think you have another answer for this question where you can argue more.. ;)

Comment: Don't get upset. I was simply pointing out that your answer does not address the question. The other answer, while the reasoning is superficial, at least does that.

Comment: Alright..n nothing to get upset about it mate.. (y)

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are fine, but I wanted the most conciseness without sacrificing performance or complexity. Here is a modified version of @Wikiti's answer. I don't think it's necessary to define falsey values. Anything contained in the set of true values can be effectively considered as 'true', otherwise treat it as false.

Note that this is intentionally different than the ActiveModel Boolean class, which will treat everything as true if it is NOT contained in a falsey value. If you're looking for strict boolean flags, IMO it's a better practice to have false as the default value, and true to only be returned if the value is explicitly defined as such. Programming languages tend to use false as the default in a boolean variable, so this better practice is grounded in intuitiveness.

```rb
class EnvTrue 
  TRUE_VALUES = %w[1 y Y true TRUE True].freeze

  def self.[](key)
    TRUE_VALUES.include?(v)
  end
end

# Usage example:
EnvTrue['MY_VARIABLE'] # returns true or false
ENV['MY_VARIABLE'] # When you want the actual value
```

Comment: Falsey values are already defined by Rails, so there is no need to re-define them but for truthy: `
FALSE_VALUES = [ false, 0, "0", :"0", "f", :f, "F", :F, "false", :false, "FALSE", :FALSE, "off", :off, "OFF", :OFF, ].to_set.freeze`.

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Type/Boolean.html

Comment: @PereJoanMartorell Edited answer to communicate intent more clearly. I don't think your argument applies to what I was going for here. Wikiti's answer also addresses the same point.